# how to insert values from comma separator in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

in sql store procedure i have variable

```
 IN `table2variables` VARCHAR(5000),
```

which hold values like this : table2variables ="88,61,35"

now i want to insert those values in table like this :

```
INSERT into table2(id, val) values ([id],"88");
INSERT into table2(id, val) values ([id],"61");
INSERT into table2(id, val) values ([id],"35");
```

so question is how can i get values from that variable?
and write only one sentence to INSERT?

Comment: split field into individual values, insert individual values.

Comment: not sure, how can we achieve this,  table2variables can hold any numbers of values with comma separator.

Comment: If the number of values within the field is fixed, then using substring_index() will help you. If this number is dynamic, then you have to write a stored procedure to do it in mysql only. May be easier to implement in a traditional programming language.

Comment: could show me an example ?

Comment: @Barmar Thanks for comment,, i am not inserting "88,61,35"  to one row, i want to insert each number to row.( here it will be 3 rows), is that create an issue?

Comment: I know, I deleted my comment.

Answer (score -1):

You can use backslash(\) to insert commas into values. The backslash acts like an escape character. The concept is very much similar to many programming languages.

```
INSERT into table2(id, val) values ([id],"88\,61\,35");
```

To update:

```
UPDATE table2 
SET val = "50\,60\,90"
WHERE id = 999
```

Comment: and what if i want to update that records ?

Comment: I updated my answer @user0293

Comment: is any other way to replace string ="88,61,35" to "88\,61\,35" , in javascript,php or sql?

Comment: Commas don't need to be escaped inside strings.

Comment: What does this answer have to do with the question. He doesn't want a comma-separated list in a single column. He wants to split the string in the stored procedure, and put each element in a separate row.